# How to correctly handle click events on Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

There is a task to make smt like todo list on widget (with dynamic number of elements),
how to organize this list for click support on this elements.
I only found how add click event on one widget layout element (with `setOnClickPendingIntent`),
and how send text to widget element TextView.

But it's unclear how handle click events for sub-elements, or how get click coordinates(or item) where was click event.
I saw widget "**Agenda widget**" - and it work fine with clicking on different calendar rows.

I will be very much appreciated for help.

Answer (score 5):

> But it's unclear how handle click
>   events for sub-elemets

Use `setOnClickPendingIntent()`.

> or how get click coordinates(or item)
>   where was click event

Use different `Intents` inside of the `PendingIntents` passed to `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. By "different", you need something other than an extra to be different, such as a distinct action string.

Comment: The sample project link is dead and I can't seem to find where it was moved to. Could you update this?

Comment: @NickGarvey: Sorry, I do not have a current project that demonstrates this.