# Using ViewFlipper in a widget with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building a widget that has several pages of information. Only one page will be displayed at a time, and when a user taps on the widget, the next page will be displayed. I would like to create this functionality by using a ViewFlipper, however I can not find any documentation on how to implement it for a widget.

Here is skeleton code I am using while trying to get the ViewFlipper to work.

I have widget (DivisionStandings ) that has the content inserted into the layout (mainLayout) with a service (UpdateService).

When running the widget, I initially see the text for header1 set to "Updated Header" as intended. Touching the widget however does nothing.

```
[BroadcastReceiver (Label = "aaWdiget")]
[IntentFilter (new string [] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData ("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/divisionstandings")]
public class DivisionStandings : AppWidgetProvider
{
    public override void OnUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
    context.StartService (new Intent (context, typeof (UpdateService)));
    }
}


[Service]
public class UpdateService : Service
{
    public override void OnStart (Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        RemoteViews mainView= new RemoteViews (this.PackageName, Resource.Layout.mainLayout);;
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName (this,  "mlbstandings.DivisionStandings");
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance (this);

       mainView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.header1, "Updated Header");

        ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper)Resource.Id.viewFlipper1;
        flipper.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => { 
            flipper.ShowNext(); 
        };

        manager.UpdateAppWidget (thisWidget, mainView);
    }


<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header1"
            android:text="---Header" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header2"
            android:text="Other Header" />       
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem probably is in `ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper)Resource.Id.viewFlipper1;`
'Resource.Id.viewFlipper1' is `int` not `ViewFlipper`

<strike>So you need to get you view by id like that:</strike>

```
ViewFlipper flipper = mainView.FindViewById<ViewFlipper> (Resource.Id.viewFlipper1)
```

**Update**
since it looks like there is no method to access directly to views you need to use `mainView.SetOnClickPendingIntent` and than do yor action in `OnRecive()` method.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932752/1558147) some more information in Java

Comment: FindViewById is not available to the Service class.

Comment: @Mason240 it must be available for View class. So I call it from mainView. Or it's not View?

Comment: @ad1Dima - since this is a Widget, it's a RemoteViews, which does not have a `findViewById()`

Comment: @Mason240 you're right. So I updated my answer with some new information.